# Bitdefender threat error even though I never installed Bitdefender

Tags: malware, antimalware

I got this strange error today:

> A problem has occured in BitDefender Threat Scanner. A file containing error information has been created at C:\Windows\Temp\BitDefender Threat Scanner.dmp

I can see the file is there. But I've never installed Bit Defender on the machine as far as I know. It's a Win2012 R2 machine I use as a development machine. There's ITBrain by Teamviewer which does malware detection. It hasn't picked anything up nor has MalwareBytes which I downloaded to scan the machine after the error. I spoke to Bitdefender and they have said they would look at it. I was wondering if anyone here had any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I got to the bottom of it. I actually spoke to BitDefender. I use some malware detection software from TeamViewer called ITBrain. That was the culprit. It uses some "drivers" (BitDefender's term) in it's software and the error was from that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You have Ad-Aware by Lavasoft installed,which uses the Bitdefender engine. or more than one Anti-Virus installed on your computer at the same time
You can read topic for find solution [here](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/604043/bitdefender-threat-scanner/)

Or You download file .iso Win2012 R2 machine which compact with Bitdefender free
If it's Ad-Aware, you should install [Revo Uninstaller Pro](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) for uninstall.
What's antivirus software are you using on Windows Server 2012 now?

Comment: Yes it is a trial I so I was using to test some features. I've looking in programs and can't see the software though.